# Can't reach MySQL hosted DB from Docker .NET Core

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-core, connection, digital-ocean

I’ve got a DigitalOcean Droplet that run Ubuntu and I’ve installed MySQL to it. I can reach it from my computer with SSH connection from MySQL workbench, so the remote access is Ok.
The hostname is 127.0.0.1

```
The bind address in my mysqld.cnf: 127.0.0.1
```

I’ve got a .NET Core API and I would like to use Docker to run it. I made the container push to docker hub and pulled it to the droplet. When I try to run I get this error:

> An error occurred using the connection to database “ on server
>   ‘127.0.0.1’.

My connection string:

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=pass”
```

I tried to server: `localhost`

IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1 so I tried this to connectionString as well.

I don’t understand why can I connect to DB from MySQL workbench and cannot from .NET Core Web API.

The .NET Core version is `3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your .NET Core is inside container. Thus if you try to connect `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, it will try to connect the container itself, not the host. Since your MySQL is on your host, not inside the container, you can access it with other IP.

For example you have `eth0` or `enps0` or something like that, then that interface have IP `192.168.1.2`, then you can use this IP as connection string.

---

Or, the alternate way, is using `--network host` when creating container. In this way, if you use 127.0.0.1, it will try to connect the host.